# pyspark reduceByKey not subscriptable error

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

during practice pyspark

```py
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext

conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("PopularMovies_Repartition") 
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf)

def f(x,y) :
    return x[0]+y[0]

sumRating = ratingRdd.reduceByKey(f) # (movie id , (sum of rating,count of rating) )
print(sumRating.collect())
```

the rating RDD looks like

ratingRdd.take(5) : [(242, (3, 1)), (302, (3, 1)), (377, (1, 1)), (51, (2, 1)), (346, (1, 1))]
it occurs error by reduceByKey

```py
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 194.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 194.0 (TID 165, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/content/drive/MyDrive/ColabStorage/spark/spark-2.4.8-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 377, in main
    process()
  File "/content/drive/MyDrive/ColabStorage/spark/spark-2.4.8-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 372, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/content/drive/MyDrive/ColabStorage/spark/spark-2.4.8-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2499, in pipeline_func
    return func(split, prev_func(split, iterator))
  File "/content/drive/MyDrive/ColabStorage/spark/spark-2.4.8-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2499, in pipeline_func
    return func(split, prev_func(split, iterator))
  File "/content/drive/MyDrive/ColabStorage/spark/spark-2.4.8-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 352, in func
    return f(iterator)
  File "/content/drive/MyDrive/ColabStorage/spark/spark-2.4.8-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1861, in combineLocally
    merger.mergeValues(iterator)
  File "/content/drive/MyDrive/ColabStorage/spark/spark-2.4.8-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/shuffle.py", line 240, in mergeValues
    d[k] = comb(d[k], v) if k in d else creator(v)
  File "/content/drive/MyDrive/ColabStorage/spark/spark-2.4.8-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/util.py", line 99, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<ipython-input-73-c4a0c8a5a249>", line 3, in g
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

but it's working well when f return `(x[0]+y[0] , 1)`

May I guess why it happened?

Answer (score 1):

Its throwing error, since you have return function for (k,v) pair instead of function for (k,(v1,v2)) pair.
Please write as either of below you will get right answer.

```
sumRating = ratingRdd.reduceByKey(lambda x,y : (x[0]+y[0],x[1]))
```

(or)

```
def f(x,y) :
   return (x[0]+y[0],x[1])

sumRating = ratingRdd.reduceByKey(f)
```

Whereas its not throwing error when you written code for function f return as "(x[0]+y[0] , 1)", since 1 is being used as placeholder for v2 value. Hope it clarifies your doubt.

Also please note if you want only (movie id ,sum of rating) then you can write code as below

```
sumRating = ratingRdd.map(lambda x: (x[0],x[1][0])).reduceByKey(lambda a,b : a+b)
```